# My form continues to submit data when the username value is empty and the code is meant to rpevent that. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript

I have made sure the Javascript is linked to the HTML I have also tried many Javascript online validation websites but none seem to have a solution to what I'm experiencing.

If the username value is empty the code is meant to show an error message and turn the username input border red hence the class changes but it seems that form continues to submit without showing any error messages.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('Username');
const password = document.getElementById('signup-password');
const confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm_password');
const email = document.getElementById('email');

if (form) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    checkInputs();
  })
};

function checkInputs() {
  const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
  const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
  const confirm_passwordValue = confirm_password.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();

  if (usernameValue === ' ' || usernameValue == null) {
    setErrorFor(username, 'Username required');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(username);
  }
}


function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

  small.innerText = message;

  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {

  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control success'
}
```

This is also the relevant HTML

```
    <body>
      <div class="Container">
        <div class="Header"><h2>Create Account</h2></div>
        <form class="form" id="form">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label class="Username" for="username">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="Username" placeholder = "yeeno3">
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label class="email" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder = "zoroisstrongerthanluffy@gmail.com">
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label class="password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder = "Password">
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label class="confirm_password" for="password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirm_password" placeholder = "Confirm Password">
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
            <input type="submit" style="display: none"/>
            <button>Submit</button>
            <input type="submit" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" />
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: `if (form) {` ... is form truthy there?

Comment: `usernameValue === ' '` checks whether `usernameValue` is equal to exactly one blank space, not if it is an empty string; that would be `usernameValue === ''`

Comment: On a side note, it is advisable to avoid setting variable names equal to element IDs as some browsers automatically generate global variables for each element with an ID and this might generates naming conflicts.

Comment: I've changed the code to usernameValue === '' I still get the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure the ID of your username input is `Username` (with a capital "U"), given the fact that all other input elements are all lower-case? Can you share the relevant HTML code, please?

Comment: Providing you fix that `usernameValue === ' '` to `usernameValue === ''`, the part of code you shared seems to work properly (see: https://jsfiddle.net/9fg2ds7h/2/); it looks like the problem might be in the CSS

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with another question; yours is not about the error message showing or not but about the form submitting even in case of error. Anyway, if you check the JSFiddle I linked in my previous comment, you can verify that the form is not submitted (you can test it by commenting and uncommenting `e.preventDefault()`). Whatever is submitting your form, is not included in the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing `usernameValue === ' '` to `usernameValue === ''`. You have trimmed your `usernameValue`, so it will never be equal to a single space, i.e. `' '`

Answer (score 0):

### The problem is here:

```js
if (usernameValue === ' ' || usernameValue == null) { //compare this
if (usernameValue === '' || usernameValue == null) { // with this
```

You need to remove that space between quotes.